# Powershell script from Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, powershell

I am developing Angular 4 app and I want to run a power-shell script when user clicks on some link.
Can this be done with writing proxy HTTP service that will provide this power shell script in response and run on client?

Comment: Being able to do so would be a security risk and client script execution is sand boxed in browser by default. Therefore I dont think it's possible to download run a powershell script on client

Comment: better to have desktop application instead of web application for this use case OR just provide the instruction to the user to copy the script and run it manually.